# WPF Datagrid Selection Issue

Tags: wpf, list, datagrid, selection

In my WPF application I have one datagrid and one textbox. In the textChanged event of the textbox, I put this:

```
myDatagrid.ItemsSource = 
myListOfObjects.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(MyTextBox.Text)); //Filter

if (myDatagrid.Items.Count > 0)  // If no itens, then do nothing
{
     myDatagrid.SelectedIndex = 0;  // If has at least one item, select the first
}

myDatagrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Note that I force the selection when the text changes, in the first row of the DataGrid.

But unfortunately, **the color of the row does not change to blue**, making it hard to see the selection.

I realy need this, because in the PreviewKeyDown event of the textbox I have this:

```
    private void myTextBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            if (!(myDataGrid.SelectedIndex <= 0))
            {
                myDataGrid.SelectedIndex--;  // Go one position Up
            }
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            if (!(myDataGrid.SelectedIndex == myDataGrid.Items.Count - 1))
            {
                myDataGrid.SelectedIndex++;  // Go one position Down
            }
        }
    }
```

So, when the textbox is focused and the user press the Up or the Down key, the selection does not appear to change.

Any idea of how I can make the selected item on the datagrid change it's color to blue?

Other thing: in my virtual machine, it works!! With the same code! How it's possible?

I think that is the aeroglass, but I change the theme to the Windows 7 Basic (same in the virtual machine) and still don't work.

Thanks, and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try using SelectedItem? you could always create a new property and bind to this and then set this item directly rather than using the selected index. Hopefully this would trigger any additional logic in the DataGrid control :)

```
//Declare property outside of method
public ObjectType SelectedItem { get; set; }

//Set datacontext on load
DataContext = this;

myDatagrid.ItemsSource = myListOfObjects.Where(item => item.Name.Contains(MyTextBox.Text)); //Filter

if (myDatagrid.Items.Count > 0)  // If no itens, then do nothing
{
     SelectedItem = myDatagrid.ItemSource[0];  // If has at least one item, select the first
}

myDatagrid.Items.Refresh();
```

Also don't forget to set your binding!

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

hope that helps!

Comment: Hello friend, thanks to answer my question. 

It works in the same way of the other code, so the datagrid selected row color is not blue.

I think that is because the focus is in the textbox, and not in the datagrid.

Comment: Is there any way to make the selected item turns blue without the datagrid is focused?

Comment: @Guilherme maybe you could do myDataGrid.Focus(); would that help?

Comment: Yes, it's make blue the selected row, but if I do this, my textbox will lose the focus and the user will need to click in the textbox to continue writing.

Comment: Without focus, the selected item works, but the color is light gray and it's hard to see. The problem is the color.

Comment: @Guilherme Hmm I see what you mean, you could delay the focus using the dispatcher? then it would only happen once nothing else is being processed?

Comment: I have a dispatcher timer in my application that raises one event every second. How can I delay the focus?

Comment: @Guilherme rather than using a timer, try using the DispatcherPriority and set that to something high, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx for exact prioritys